# How to verify that the eureka clients are enabled SSL or not from the InstanceInfo from another client?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

My case is I want to make a request from one of eureka clients to another one. todo that I  want to verify the the client has enabled SSL or not. because when I make the request from another client, I use the Ip address of the client that I want to make the request. but also I want to clarify that eureka has SSL enabled or not use make the request. I can put the details in the `metadata` whether that particular instance has enabled the SSL or not when the server is started but I think there should have a proper method to do that by using info data. could you please give me a suggestion for that.

Comment: can you please share your ssl configuration?

Comment: in my case I don't know the client will enable the SSL or not. that's why I want to Verify  the clint has enabled the SSL or not. because this is a third party library that can use with the Eureka. I want to verify that the client has enabled or not SSL and send the request to that server. because i want to build the URL `http://....` or `https://....`